# what does getConfirmationTts() in voice interaction do

Tags: android

[the clip of the code written for using voice interaction which is used in another Java file I have already tried importing android.app.VoiceInteractor but its not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t6O5.png)

Comment: I have heard `getconfirmationTts()` method first time..

Comment: i got it from Google developers website but its not given properly what is it and how to use it

Comment: Can you please post the link ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/interaction/voice-interactions

Answer (score 0):

You may have imported all necessary classes in your code. As your snippet you forgot to extend that, But you are already extending `AppCompatActivity` so that you can't extend another class in the same Activity. What you need to do is create another class inside `MyVoiceActivity` and extend `VoiceInteractor.ConfirmationRequest` in that class.

Your Activity will look something like this

```
public class MyVoiceActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

        class Confirm extends VoiceInteractor.ConfirmationRequest {

             //All method you wanted goes here

        }

}
```

Comment: but the onResume function has to be outside the inner class in which we are extending VoiceInteractor.ConfirmationRequest

Comment: @PushkarSuman I am really sorry bro. This is the most disgusting tutorial I ever found. what is [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/VoiceInteractor.java)   about ? one up for your question..

Comment: i need to use voice integration with my app to control the app functionality using user's voice command

Comment: Have you considered [this](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html) then ?